# executing queries with datetime in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, .nettiers

I use sql server 2008 R2 as a data store.

Until now on the test machine I had the english version of the software and used to make queries formatting the datetime field as

```
fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

now I have deployed the database on another server which is in the italian language. I shall change the format in my code to

```
fromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Is there a way to make the query in a neutral format?

thanks!

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention that I am using NetTiers with CodeSmith. Here's a complete sample

```
AppointmentQuery aq = new AppointmentQuery(true, true);
aq.AppendGreaterThan(AppointmentColumn.AppointmentDate, fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
aq.AppendLessThan(AppointmentColumn.AppointmentDate, toDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
AppointmentService aSvc = new AppointmentService();
TList<Appointment> appointmentsList = aSvc.Find(aq);
```

Comment: I think `yyyy-MM-dd` (among others) is universal.

Comment: As others have said, but it's worth repeating, you really shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @ProfK: why I should'nt?

Comment: to be fair to @ProfK, he commented before your edit which does change the context of the question considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISO 8601 *Data elements and interchange formats — Information interchange — Representation of dates and times*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) allows both the YYYY-MM-DD and YYYYMMDD.  SQL Server recognises the ISO specifications.

> Although the standard allows both the
>   YYYY-MM-DD and YYYYMMDD formats for
>   complete calendar date
>   representations, if the day [DD] is
>   omitted then only the YYYY-MM format
>   is allowed. By disallowing dates of
>   the form YYYYMM, the standard avoids
>   confusion with the truncated
>   representation YYMMDD (still often
>   used).

I prefer the YYYYMMDD format, but I think that's because I only knew about that to start with, and to me it seems more universal, having done away with characters that might be considered locale specific.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You should share the code you are using to execute the query, but I guess you are building a SQL query dynamically using string concats to build the query and the arguments. You should rather use a parameterised query then you can pass the data as a date object and no need to converto a string.</strike>

For example if your query could be something like this

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "select * from Orders where fromDT = @fromDate", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", fromDate);

...
```

As a good side effect, this will reduce your risk of [SQL injection](http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-injection-are-parameterized-queries.html).

**Update:** After your edit which does change the question context significantly, and I have to admit that I have Zero knowledge of the .netTiers project. But just out of curiosity have you tried just passing the date instances directly as in the following?

```
AppointmentQuery aq = new AppointmentQuery(true, true); 
aq.AppendGreaterThan(AppointmentColumn.AppointmentDate, fromDate); 
aq.AppendLessThan(AppointmentColumn.AppointmentDate, toDate); 
AppointmentService aSvc = new AppointmentService(); 
TList<Appointment> appointmentsList = aSvc.Find(aq);
```

Comment: no I am not using string concats. Please see my edit for more details. I have forgotten to mention that I was using the Strong typed query objects from NetTiers. thanks

Comment: @Lorenzo, I updated my response to address the new info you provided in your question, but this has taken the question into a technology I have not worked with take what I say here with a grain of salt.

Comment: No Chris I cannot pass to the various append methods date instances because they only accept string parameters. :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I always use `yyyy-MM-dd`. This also makes it sortable as a string.

However, a date is a date is a date. There's no need to change the date to a string. In .NET, user `DateTime`.